# how to read data from json in swift2

Tags: json, swift

I am trying to read email from a json file in swift(2.2) which is:

```
 { "employees" : [
  {
    "name": "sudhanshu",
    "email": "sudhanshu.bharti@digitalavenues.com",
    "password": "password"
    "profilePic": ""
 },
 {
    "name": "prokriti",
    "email": "prokriti.roy@digitalavenues.com",
    "password": "password@123",
    "profilePic": ""
  }
]}
```

But i am getting error " Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Unescaped control character around character 128." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Unescaped control character around character 128.}" i have seen earlier posts but unable to find where exactly problem is??

```
if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Employees", ofType: "json") {
        if let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: path) {
            do {
                let jsonResult: NSDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary

                if let error = jsonResult["error"] {
                    print("Error is: \(error)")
                } else {
                    if let person = jsonResult["email"] {
                        print(person) // dictionary[@"quotables"]
                    }
                }

            } catch let error as NSError {
             print("Error is: \(error)")
            }

        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access directly email key from the dictionary. while you need to first access array from the key "employees" & then you need to get value from "email" key.

```
if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Employees", ofType: "json") {
if let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: path) {
    do {
        let jsonResult: NSDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary

        if let error = jsonResult["error"] {
            print("Error is: \(error)")
        } else {
            let person = jsonResult["employees"] as! NSArray
            for i in 0..<person.count
            {
                let dict = person.objectAtIndex(i) as! NSDictionary
                let strEmail = dict["email"] as! String
                print(strEmail)
            }
        }

    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Error is: \(error)")
    }

}
```

Comment: Please consider explaining rather than just putting out the code. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

> "password": "password”

should be

> "password": "password"

You have an invalid `”` character instead of a `"`.

**Update**

Now that you've fixed your invalid character, you can access your data. But you're trying to cast as an NSDictionary something that's actually an array, if I believe the JSON excerpt you showed us.

So you should do something like this instead in your `do`:

```
if let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) as? [[String: String]] {
    for jsonDictionary in jsonResult {
        if let person = jsonDictionary["email"] {
            print(person)
        }
    }
}
```

**Update and fix**

```
if let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) as? [String: AnyObject] {
    if let employees = jsonResult["Employees"] as? [[String:String]] {
        for employee in employees {
            if let person = employee["email"] {
                print(person)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Eric D, but i am unable to access email here.

Comment: i am getting "nil" in if statement  jsonResult["email"]

Comment: @S.Bharti Analyze the structure of the JSON. `{}` represents a dictionary, `[]` an array. The root object is a dictionary `employees` including an array of dictionaries with the employee data. And use Swift native collection types rather than the type-unspecified Foundation ones.

Comment: not working for me, getting 0 elements in "jsonResult"

Comment: I've updated my answer (I think I missed a part previously). The same ideas apply, though, it's just a difference in the JSON structure.